# Make Jenkins 'Execute Shell' exactly the same as when using bash shell

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, jenkins, zsh

So I've come across a few things now that seem to just not work right in the jenkins 'Execute shell' stage of a build. These works fine when logged in as the same user on the same machine when typing into bash/zsh/terminal.

Is there some setting somewhere to make these match exactly, in terms of permissions, output etc... seems like Jenkins is in some sort of weird sandbox and its really frustrating.

A few things that have tripped so far is ruby commands like

```
bundle exec nanoc compile
```

and

```
cap deploy
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

More info:
Jenkins is running on Mac OSX Mavericks.

Comment: There is no sandbox (unless your OS is providing one via SELinux or such, which we couldn't tell with only the information provided here). Moreover, bash, zsh, and POSIX sh are not compatible with each other -- if you're testing code against zsh and then running it against POSIX sh (or bash started as `sh`, which is POSIX compatibility mode) in production, that's setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: Anyhow, we'd need a much, much more specific description of the failure mode -- not just "these commands fail", but "these commands fail in this exact way".

Comment: ...well, let me clarify the above "not compatible with each other" -- POSIX sh defines a minimal shell language. bash implements that specification, with a lot of extensions. zsh *does not* implement the spec, as zsh chooses to do saner things in places where the standard is stupid (but, in doing so, makes itself incompatible with the standard). Bottom line remains: You can't write something for Shell A and reasonably expect it to work in Shell B.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah pretty new to jenkins and as I said below, thought there might have been a root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a situation where details matter.

The most common case where commands work during interactive testing but fail when run from a service is a simple dependency on environment variables, dotfiles, file permissions, and similar setup.

You can test as the user you're running Jenkins under using `su - jenkins` (presuming a user named "jenkins"). Next, check the environment variables in-scope for your runtime environment; one way to do this is simply running the `env` command inside your Jenkins job, then using `env -i K1=V1 K2=V2 ... your-command` to simulate that same environment within your tests.

Finally, be sure that the shell being used to test is the same one being used at runtime. If Jenkins is starting `/bin/sh`, you need to test with `/bin/sh` -- not `/bin/bash` (even if `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `bash`!), and certainly not `zsh`.

If your failure cases are interesting enough, though, you may be hitting OS-level security frameworks. There's no way to determine that without precise details on the failures, which are not given here (and aren't really topical on StackOverflow anyhow; this would be a question for ServerFault or such if you were hitting restrictions of that type). Your system administration staff are the best folks to help here.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realise this was a too general topic. I was seeing some inconsistencies across the board and thought I'd missed a more general setting - apologies

Comment: switching to bash in Terminal helped me debug this quicker, and it seemed to be my version of Ruby that was stuffing things up.